# How do I obtain better quality copies of this patent other than what I can print off this site? The patent holder was my father

Tags: us1826708

Conduit receptacle
US 1826708 A

How do I obtain better quality copies of this patent other than what I can print off this site?

```
Publication number  US1826708 A
Publication type    Grant
Publication date    Oct 13, 1931
Filing date Jan 21, 1930
Priority date   Jan 21, 1930
Inventors   Jacob Colitz
Original Assignee   Jacob Colitz
Referenced by (1), Classifications (6)
External Links: USPTO, USPTO Assignment, Espacenet
```

Answer (score 2):

Go to the source: [the patent office](http://www.uspto.gov/products/library/) maintains a network of libraries that hold patents back to at least 1870.  They will be the best copy quality available.

Answer (score 1):

If this is seems better, you can get it [at USPTO](http://www.google.com/patents/us1826708).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The original documents at [Espacenet](http://worldwide.espacenet.com/publicationDetails/originalDocument?CC=US&NR=1826708A&KC=A&FT=D&ND=3&date=19311013&DB=worldwide.espacenet.com&locale=en_EP) are normally 300DPI but at that age they may have come from scans of photocopies and hence skewed a bit

[image]